# apt-get update failing when building a docker image with ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to build a docker image using ubuntu:latest on a Mac. I am using a shell file to collect the set up steps but the building stops when the container runs `apt-get update`.

The error is:

```
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
```

My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN chmod +x set_up.sh
RUN ./set_up.sh
```

while `set_up.sh` is

```
#!/bin/sh

#1. Update package manager 
apt-get  update
```

For context, I get the same error if I use

```
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
root@fca959160783:/# apt-get update
0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

with the command hanging at `0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]` for a long time before producing the rest of the outcome.

I am new to docker but I've been running the same code yesterday on a different WiFi connection and I didn't experience any issue. I have tried adding the options `--network=host` to the build command or my current DNS IP address in the `docker run` version of the example but I get the same issues and I am not sure what to do now. I'd appreciate any suggestions you might have on this issue.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: why do you need set_up.sh?

Comment: You are right, I don't need it. I am using it just because I collected the required packages and some other installation commands in this file and I am now moving the codes to docker. Anyway, the issue is not in the image that I am trying to build as I have the same error with the official ubuntu container.

Answer (score 0):

It could be architecture mismatch.
Check docker architecture with: `docker info | grep Architecture`
Check image architecture with: `docker inspect ubuntu`

In the case of mismatch you should reinstall docker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've installed docker using the docker desktop installer from their website. `docker info` gives `Architecture: x86_64` and `docker inspect ubuntu` is `Architecture: amd64`.

Comment: Maybe try to install with brew

Comment: Not sure this is it - I've tried with `alpine` instead of ubuntu and I managed to install packages with `apk` even if `docker inspect alpine` gives the same architecture as ubuntu.

Comment: You can define the architecture by ubuntu repository like deb [arch=amd64] link_to_repo. Looks like alpine is not so peaky.